# Getting response time using webrequest C#

Tags: c#, security, html, webrequest

I am trying to connect to a secure webpage to get the response time: however, I keep getting this error

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. - System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Here is the code

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
string url = "some url"; 
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });//requires that .NEt 4.5 be installed but not targeted

string fileName = "file ocation";//<--Example
WebClient WC = new WebClient();
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string x = "";

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);

try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    timer.Stop();
    TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
    writer.WriteLine(currentDateTime.ToString() + " - " + timeTaken.ToString());
    writer.Close();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    writer.WriteLine(currentDateTime.ToString() + " " + ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException.ToString(), true);
}
```

}

Comment: Your server deliberately closes your connection without returning an answer. So what is your question?

Comment: How can I get the response time without it throwing an error

Comment: Your server doesn't return a response, just closes the connection. What time do you want to measure?..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  I didnt understand why the code was erroring; however, 
since I was using VS 2010 it only goes up to .net 4.0.  Therefore, there are missing enum for the SecurityProtocol.  Once I cast the integer for the missing enum it worked

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)48 | (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });//requires that .NEt 4.5 be installed but not targeted